# Error in SQL server connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have an ASP.net website and I have uploaded it on a free hosting site. I have uploaded all files and directories. Changed the connection string with the connection string given by the hosting site. But still I am receiving this error. Error message is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

http://opacpsu-001-site1.smarterasp.net/psu-home1.aspx

Here is the connection string give by the hosting site.

```
"Data Source=SQL5013.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B4835_OPAC;User Id=DB_9B4835_OPAC_admin;Password=12345678;"
```

What should I do?

Okay so I forgot to show the configuration in the Web.config file.

Here it is.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="OPACConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5013.Smarterasp.net;Initial Catalog=DB_9B4835_OPAC;User Id=DB_9B4835_OPAC_admin;Password=12345678;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are separate connection strings for access from inside and outside of their network? For example, `SQL5013.Smarterasp.net` might be the external address but it might be a different one internally...

Comment: Please check [this steps](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

Comment: I really don't quite know if there is an internal address. I have done this before but this is the first time I have had this problem. I have already re-uploaded all directories and files.

Comment: @PaulAndrewRoa Are you 100% sure it is using the right connection string and pulling the right one from the web.config (by the right name, etc)?

Comment: Simnply replace connection string given by hosting site in web.config, We can see them to be different

Comment: It is `Data Source=SQL5009.myASP.NET` in your web.config rather than `Data Source=SQL5013.Smarterasp.net`

Comment: @Durgesh Chaudhary Yep, I forgot to changed that. I already changed it but the it still shows the same error.

Comment: I can also see different DB and User ID over there 835 and 884.

Comment: http://www.vadimtabakman.com/connection-string-tester.aspx when downloaded exe, your configuration looks fine, http://i.stack.imgur.com/KQAgW.png

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary Yep, I have already changed that too.

Comment: Last thing then left is to contact Hosting Service Provider if the DB is up, and/or accessbile from outside if you are connecting it from SSMS and/or app not inside network